Name all rows with the Index name
I have a strange request, easy to understand but should be very complicated to realize in my opinion. I have a dataframe composed of several spreadsheet excel (using df concat).
I would like to use all the df names (the excel spreadsheet name) to name all my rows, to know in which spreadsheet is coming from this row. Because thereafter, I will mix those datas.
Thank you for your time/help :)
Use df name as rows name.

I believe that read_excel returns a dictionary of dataframes with the sheet name as key
you can loop through the dictionary and add each dataframe the sheet name column and pd.concat the dictionary right after.

Ze'ev as yesterday, thank you very much for your help. However, you are overestimating my Python capacity hahaha :) , but I understood, I will try

Suppose we have an Excel workbook like this:

We can use pd.read_excel with sheet_name=None to read this into a dictionary with the sheet names as keys:
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'myfile.xlsx'

dict_df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)

dict_df

{'Sheet1':   Col1  Col2
 0    A     1
 1    B     2
 2    C     3,
 'Sheet2':   Col1  Col2
 0    D     4
 1    E     5
 2    F     6}

Now, we can use pd.concat to add the dictionary keys to the index values. As of pd 2.0.0 you can use df.add_prefix with axis=0:
# pd >= 2.0.0
df = pd.concat([v.add_prefix(f"{k}_", axis=0) for k, v in dict_df.items()])

df

         Col1  Col2
Sheet1_0    A     1
Sheet1_1    B     2
Sheet1_2    C     3
Sheet2_0    D     4
Sheet2_1    E     5
Sheet2_2    F     6

For earlier versions, you can overwrite the index using df.set_index:
# pd < 2.0.0
df = pd.concat([v.set_index(f"{k}_" + v.index.astype(str)) 
                for k, v in dict_df.items()])

# same result

But it may be nicer to add the sheet names as a separate level, making use of the keys and names parameters:
df = pd.concat([v for v in dict_df.values()], 
               keys=dict_df.keys(), 
               names=['Sheets', 'Rows'])

df

            Col1  Col2
Sheets Rows           
Sheet1 0       A     1
       1       B     2
       2       C     3
Sheet2 0       D     4
       1       E     5
       2       F     6

Or simply:
df = pd.concat(dict_df, names=['Sheets', 'Rows'])
# same result

E.g., this way you can easily select a particular sheet:
df.loc['Sheet1']

     Col1  Col2
Rows           
0       A     1
1       B     2
2       C     3


If you are reading from multiple Excel workbooks and also want to include the file names, you can do something like this:
workbooks = ['myfile.xlsx', 'myfile2.xlsx'] # `myfile2` here a copy of `myfile`

nested_dict = {(wb,k): v for wb in workbooks 
               for k, v in pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name=None).items()}

df = pd.concat([v for v in nested_dict.values()], 
               keys=nested_dict.keys(), 
               names=['Filename', 'Sheets', 'Rows'])

df

                         Col1  Col2
Filename     Sheets Rows           
myfile.xlsx  Sheet1 0       A     1
                    1       B     2
                    2       C     3
             Sheet2 0       D     4
                    1       E     5
                    2       F     6
myfile2.xlsx Sheet1 0       A     1
                    1       B     2
                    2       C     3
             Sheet2 0       D     4
                    1       E     5
                    2       F     6

Or again:
df = pd.concat(nested_dict, names=['Filename', 'Sheets', 'Rows'])
# same result

Selecting Sheet1 from the first workbook:
df.loc[('myfile.xlsx', 'Sheet1')]

     Col1  Col2
Rows           
0       A     1
1       B     2
2       C     3


Thank you very much ouroboros, small question: What are k and v ?

dictionaries in python are sets of key: value pairs. So, one commonly uses k: v. To loop through both k and v simultaneously, you use dict.items(), to get just the keys, you use dict.keys(); just the values: dict.values().

I have a numpy error : TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

At what stage of trying which solution? The one with a single Excel workbook, or the one with multiple ones? What is the exact line that is throwing an error?

Sorry I cannot send you my script , because Stack says that Im using AI , wich is wrong, I cannot use AI

below 2 lines : df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheets), ignore_index = False)
df = pd.concat([v for v in df.values()], keys = df.keys())

Your second line makes no sense, df is already a proper pd.DataFrame at this point. Simply pd.concat(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheets), ignore_index = False) is what you need, no? Or, adding the names: pd.concat(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheets), names=['Sheets', 'Rows']).

Indeed, no sense :) . Thank you very much for your help ouro

Ouro, Python does not like the axis mode : TypeError: add_prefix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'   , i checked and it is surely my Python version who is not update , I have pandas 0.23.4

I am seeing that I can add prefix on Colums on DataFrame and addprefix on rows on series

Updated the answer: you can use df = pd.concat([v.set_index(f"{k}_" + v.index.astype(str)) for k, v in dict_df.items()]) for pd versions < 2.0.0.

IT WORKS ouro, WTH YOU ARE LIKE THE NEXT BILL GATES OR WHAT :)
